# How can I produce an unnumbered chapter for the introduction?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

If I did

```
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Introduction}
```

then I get Chapter 0 Introduction.
I just want the word Introduction, and I want it also in the contents when I use

```
 \tableofcontents
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're working in the book documentclass, then you should use the starred version of `\chapter` to obtain a chapter without the counter visible. See

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{} \lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{First chapter} \lipsum[6-10]
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[11-15]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[16-20]
\end{document}​
```

The addition of `\markboth{...}{...}` ensures that the correct page heading is followed as with the other regular (unstarred) `\chapter{...}` commands.

Comment: what is lipsum?

Comment: @Peter The `lipsum` package is just a package to produce dummy text. It's not required for the solution.

Comment: The [`lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is a LaTeX package for adding dummy text to your document. I just wanted to set up a reasonable-sized document, so I added some dummy text between the chapters. Also, here's some [detailed information](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-171.html) on the `\addcontentsline` command.

Comment: You might also want to add `\chaptermark{Introduction}` to get correct headers.

Comment: @Lockstep: ok it works but my header is now "Chapter 0. Introduction". While I have only written \chaptermark{Introduction}. Why?

Comment: @Peter: I've updated my answer to include the addition of `\markboth` that specifies the page headings. Here's some more [detailed information](http://www.uz.ac.zw/science/maths/latex/ltx-264.html) on that command.

Comment: @Werner: ok  \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{INTRODUCTION} works, I don't know why  \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{} doesn't work. thanks

Comment: @Peter: You'll notice that in the standard book documentclass the page style only has an entry on even (or left) pages. The odd (or right) page styles have no chapter marker. The basic definition is `\markboth{<left head>}{<right head>}`. That's why I only have `\markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}`.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}

\section{This is a section}

\end{document}
```

This needs to be run twice for the introduction to appear.

How LaTeX does tables of contents and similar things (tables of figures...) is that each time it finds a thing of the relevant sort (in this case a section command) it writes that information to a file (in this case `file.toc` if your main file is `file.tex`). What `\addcontentsline` does is it tells LaTeX to pay attention to this extra thing that it wouldn't normally add to the file. The three arguments are (roughly) what file to add the thing to, what sort of thing it is and what to actually add to the file at that point.

Then when it sees `\tableofcontents` it reads `file.toc` and outputs the table of contents. (This is why it won't show up on the first run through: it's read `\tableofcontents` already by the time it gets to `\addcontentsline`!)

For books, use `\chapter*` instead of `\section*` and change `section` to `chapter` in the `\addcontentsline` command

Comment: I'm working with the documentclass book and where there is the introduction in the up part of the page I read CONTENTS because before of the introduction I have the contents, how can I avoid that?

Comment: @Peter E does my edit help or is something else going on?

Answer (score 7):

In the »book« class you can divide your document into three parts (front, main, back). This has some effects that should do what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Introduction}

  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Theorie}
  \chapter{Practice}

  \appendix
  \chapter{Notes}

  \backmatter
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{key} Bibliogrpahy Item
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on how the Introduction chapter page numbers are supposed to work, this may need some further adjustment, because the `\frontmatter` material uses lower case roman numbers by default.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to set the `secnumdepth` to `-1` before the introduction chapter and then set it to whatever value you need for the subsequent chapters after the introduction chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % or some other value
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}
```